# Custom Error mode set to "RemoteOnly", debugging locally still shows custom error page

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, http-error, custom-error-handling

In two of our ASP.Net Web Applications, in the Web.Config file, we've set the Custom Error redirect to our custom error page, and set the mode to "RemoteOnly" so that when we debug locally we see any unhandled exception message displayed on the "Yellow Screen of Death" - "YSoD".

This week, we discovered that when an unhandled exception is encountered, all of a sudden we're getting our custom error pages, instead of the exception details in the "YSoD".

This applies to only two, of the several applications we're running.  I've searched high and low for a similar problem/solution, and haven't found much.

I'm trying to determine if this is an Application, IIS, or Visual Studio configuration problem.  It just started happening, and there were no significant changes made to the server, etc., to potentially explain the problem.  We have enabled IIS Failed Request Tracing, but I couldn't find anything associating this with our problem.

Given this information, what can cause this sudden change in behavior?

The back-end is a SQL Server database, using Windows Authentication, on an AWS VPC.

Comment: "We have enabled IIS Failed Request Tracing", that alone should tell where the error page comes from, IIS or ASP.NET. If the error page comes from the latter, you also need to enable ASP.NET ETW to learn more.

Comment: If it shows custom error page not YSOD, that means the request didnot get into asp.net route. Please check failed request tracing log to know what happened. Or  set <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /> to get error message of IIS module.

Comment: @BruceZhang Are you stating that if I implement the httpErrors errorMode that our exception errors will be detailed in the Yellow Screen of Death, as they used to?

Comment: @LexLi I'm not sure I follow, and I'm not extremely knowledgeable in regards to this subject.   To clarify, are you saying that the fact that we have enabled failed request tracing that should tell us that we also need to enable ETW?

Comment: Actually, HttpError and CustomError are not same. Only CustomError will affect YSOD. Httperror is for requests that failed to enter the asp.net route. An error occurs when these requests are processed by the function module of IIS, and IIS will return an error page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGT5C.png). If the request is correctly processed by IIS and entered asp.net routing, the asp.net application which has issue will return YSOD.

Comment: That makes sense.  Which is the likely culprit, causing our YSOD to not show?  Again, this is only true for two of our applications.  An additional difference between these, and the other applications working correctly, is that we're handling the "Application_Error" event in the global.asax page, as well as, the customErrors in the web.config.  Again, this just started occurring recently, and we cannot determine the root cause of this changed behavior.

Comment: It seems that the issue may be caused by Application_Error. If exception has been handled or in application_error, YSOD will not show. Custom errror page will show.